# inserting windows form data from text and combo boxes into mysql database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

i am working on an application which will allow the user to add a company via the form. i a struggling on inserting the data into the MySQL DB in the INSERT query. the query is sound as it will work when directly applied, however the application won't commit...here is my code below...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

           sqlconnection.Close()

Dim com As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO companies VALUES(company_id, '" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & RichTextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox4.Text & "', '" & TextBox5.Text & "', '" & ComboBox6.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox7.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & "', '" & ComboBox2.Text & "', '" & RichTextBox3.Text & "', '" & ComboBox5.Text & "', '" & RichTextBox2.Text & "', '" & ComboBox7.Text & "', '" & ComboBox1.Text & "', '" & ComboBox4.Text & "';", con)

        con.Open()

        com.ExecuteNonQuery()

        con.Close()

        MsgBox("committed")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: does it throws any error?

Comment: nice [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com)... plus hopefully you checked that you're specifying your data in the order that MySQL is expecting - you're not specifying WHICH fields to insert into, so you **HAVE** to do **EXACTLY** what mysql wants.

Comment: it says there is an error in SQL syntax, however when ran directly into DB with values as opposed to form item values, it works? im not sure if the problem is within the part where the form item values are in the query

Comment: where is the code for your Connection to the Database? what version of the .NET Framework are you working with?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's what you get for not using parametrized query.
Probably in one or more of your textboxes or richtextboxes an apostrophe causes your string concatenation to confuse everything.
Suppose that TextBox1 contains `'Acme's Inc.'`. Now your string query text becomes

```
INSERT INTO companies VALUES (company_id, 'Acme's Inc.', 
                                               ^
```

See the syntax error caused by blindly string concatenation?

I can't write a complete replacement of your code here because so many controls with undescriptive names. However you should write something like this

```
Dim cmdText = "INSERT INTO companies VALUES (@companyID, @param1, @param2, ....etc")
Dim com as New MySqlCommand(cmdText, con)
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyID", company_id)
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", textbox1.Text)
.... 'and so on'
con.Open()
com.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Apart from the quoting problem, correct representation of dates and decimal numbers for the underlying database system you have another big problem. [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709975/inserting-windows-form-data-from-text-and-combo-boxes-into-mysql-database/14710146#14710146) (This is just an instructive link because SQL Injection is a very large topic)

So at the end

**NEVER USE STRING CONCATENATION TO BUILD SQL QUERIES.**

Comment: I understand that you are trying to help. but you should address the problem of the SQL Connection first, because that is what the User is asking for help with. then add a side note about SQL Injection.

Comment: The OP says there is a syntax error in INSERT string, so the connection is open and working.

Comment: Re-Read the OP Post. he ran the Insert on the DataBase. he says `the query is sound as it will work when directly applied` and I see no Syntax errors in the code that is shown

Comment: @Malachi Of course the code shown is incomplete and I don't know where this sqlConnection comes from and how the `con` is initialized, but have you ever tried to run an ExecuteNonQuery with a closed connection? You don't get a syntax error in that case, but a 'ExecuteNonQuery requires an open connection', thus the connection `con` is correctly opened, then OP submit the query and the db engine parse the text and says 'SYNTAX ERROR....'. I stand by my answer, the error is in the query string not in the connection.